# Find an easier way to compare two 2-d array's independence

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

#### My question

#### 1. Intro

- ka & kb are two 2-d array all in the shape of 31*37
- They contain 2 value: 0  & 1
- **Independence**:the grid amount when only the value of ka[i, j] = 1

Using `np.mask`, they shows like this:

http://i4.tietuku.com/29adccd90484fe34.png
code here:

```
ka_select = np.ma.masked_less(ka,0.001)
pa =plt.pcolor(kb_select,cmap="Set1",alpha =0.7,facecolor = "k",edgecolor = 'k',zorder =1)
kb_select = np.ma.masked_less(kb,0.001)
pb =plt.pcolor(kb_select,cmap="Set1",alpha =0.7,facecolor = "k",edgecolor = 'k',zorder =1)
```

#### 2. My early work

- Comparing with two array ka & kb.
- If the value in index[i,j] all equal to 1, it means that this two array has overlapped in this grid.
- Count the overlapping frequency.

I have written some code about comparing two 2-d array

```
### repeat I defined is the estimate matrix to represent overlap or not in [i,j] position
repeat = np.zeros(ka.shape[0]*ka.shape[0]).reshape(ka.shape[0],ka.shape[1])

for i in range(0,ka.shape[0],1):
    for j in range(0,ka.shape[1],1):
        if (ka[i,j] == 1) & (kb[i,j] == 1) :
           repeat [i,j]=1
         else:
            repeat[u,v]  = 0
rep.append(repeat.sum())
```

- rep: the overlapping  frequency for these two 2-d array.

http://i4.tietuku.com/7121ee003ce9d034.png

#### 3. My question

When there are more than two 2-d numpy array all in the same shape with value (0,1),        How to sum the overlapping frequency?
I can compare multi array in sequence but the repeat grid would be re-counted

**More  explain**

I want to sum the amount  of array ka when ka = 1 but (kb & kc & ...) != 1 at grid[i,j] (Which I call it **independence** as shown in title).
If ka only comparing with kb, I can use **rep** to achieve that, and I haven't thought out the method dealing with more than 2 array

Comment: Your images are not showing. Could you update your question with those? They may help us understand the problem better.

Comment: Thanks for your caution, I upload it again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not using the sum of the arrays kb, ... and test the resulting elements?
An example with three grids:

```
import numpy

# some random arrays
ka = numpy.random.random_integers(0,1,37*31).reshape(31,37)
kb = numpy.random.random_integers(0,1,37*31).reshape(31,37)
kc = numpy.random.random_integers(0,1,37*31).reshape(31,37)
combined_rest = kb + kc

print "independance:", numpy.sum( (ka == 1) & (combined_rest < 2) )
```